# How to pass a Map Data Structure as an argument to a method in a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a data structure Person like a Map and  want to pass it to a function in bash script. In the method I want to retrieve “Person” like Person[Name] ,Person[Age] , Person [Dept] as Mark , 10 and Finance respectively. etc. But I am not able to get and getting the output as mentioned in the comment. Need some guidance here how to that or what I am doing wrong.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash -e
getValue(){
    local Person=$1
    echo Person[Name]
}

Person[Name]=”Mark”
Person [Age]=”10”
Person [Dept]=”Finance”
echo ${Person[Name]}   # why is  it printing Finance.I am expecting it to be printed as Mark   

getValue Person               # output is coming as Person
getValue ${Person}         # output is coming as  Finance
getValue  ${Person[@]} # output is coming as  Finance
```

Comment: Unless you use `declare -A`, `Person` is an *indexed* array. In each assignment, your keys are evaluated in an arithmetic context, with each undefined name defaulting to 0. So you have `Person[0]=Mark`, `Person[0]=10`, and `Person[0]=Finance`. Likewise, `${Person[Name]}` is the same as `${Person[0]}`, and the last assignment to index 0 was `Finance`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define Person as an associative array.
Here is the running code if you are using bash version 4 or above.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
function getValue(){
        person=$(declare -p "$1")
        declare -A person_arr=${person#*=}
        echo ${person_arr[Name]} 
        echo ${person_arr[Age]} 
        echo ${person_arr[Dept]} 
}

declare -A Person
Person[Name]="X"
Person[Age]=10
Person[Dept]="Finance"
echo ${Person[Name]}  
echo ${Person[Age]}  
echo ${Person[Dept]} 
getValue "Person"
```

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4.3 or later, a named reference makes this simpler. `declare -n person=$1; echo ${person[Name]};`.

Comment: Prior to 4.3, I would use indirect expansion, as it is probably more robust than using the output of `declare -p`. `name="$1[Name]"; echo "${!name}`.

Comment: Thanks ..Noted. `declare -n` option does not work in 4.2.46 (my version) giving error like `-n: invalid option` .

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "if you are using `bash` 4.3 or later".

Comment: I get ` declare: : not found` in this line `person=$(declare -p "$1")`, using bash `4.2.46`